# Build a dictionary with a regular expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting some data through a serial connection which I'd like to process so I can do more with it.

---

My Python script gets the variable which looks like:

```
data = "P600F600"
```

and my goal is to get this:

```
finaldata = {
  'P': 600,
  'F': 600
}
```

---

I like regular expressions and my input format is very strict so I've devised this RegEx to grab the data:

```
/([A-Z])(\d+)/
```

---

Based on my limited knowledge of Python, I've devised this.

```
finadata = eval( '{' + re.sub(r"([A-Z])(\d+)", r"'\1':\2,", data) + '}' )
```

but this is clearly a horrible and extremely hacky solution.

Comment: Downvote reason? I think my question is clear and shows what I've tried.

Comment: Question looked good to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, `re.findall` seems to be really helpful:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('([A-Z])(\d+)', 'P600F600')
[('P', '600'), ('F', '600')]
```

It just so happens that a dict can be built from this directly:

```
>>> dict(re.findall('([A-Z])(\d+)', 'P600F600'))
{'P': '600', 'F': '600'}
```

Of course, this leaves you with string values rather than integer values.  To get ints, you'd need to construct them more explicitly:

```
>>> items = re.findall('([A-Z])(\d+)', 'P600F600')
>>> {key: int(value) for key, value in items}
{'P': 600, 'F': 600}
```

Or for python2.6- compatibility:

```
>>> dict((key, int(value)) for key, value in items)
{'P': 600, 'F': 600}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was simpler than I thought. Thanks, answering my stupid question. I'll wait ~30 minutes to let other answers come in and then accept one

Answer (score 3):

Since findall already returns sequence of two-element sequences:

```
re.findall('([A-Z])(\d+)', data)  # [('P', '600'), ('F', '600')]
```

You may simply use [dict built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
import re
dict(re.findall('([A-Z])(\d+)', data))  # {'P': '600', 'F': '600'}
```

[Quoting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> If no positional argument is given, an empty dictionary is created. If
>   a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a
>   dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping
>   object. **Otherwise, the positional argument must be an iterable object.
>   Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two
>   objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new
>   dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value. If a key
>   occurs more than once, the last value for that key becomes the
>   corresponding value in the new dictionary.**